# Use jquery .prop for all checkmarks

Tags: jquery

I have a check field, special, and code that checks it.

> $('#Special').prop('checked', true);

What do I change if I add a second Special field with a different value?

Comment: You would change the selector to identify the specific elements you want to target.

Comment: I want to check all of them with the id of "Special" (or name, whichever)

Comment: That's exactly what the code you already have does.  It identifies the *one* element with the `id` value of `Special`.  And since `id` values must be unique, there's only one of them.  (If this is not the case then your HTML is invalid and the behavior of the JavaScript is undefined.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have multiple items you need to use class instead of id on your field because id must be unique on page.

Comment: There are more ways to target elements than just `class` and `id`.

Comment: I did change it to class. For some reason I had thought that id values were not supposed to be unique with check boxes.